# javascript property value dependent of other property

Tags: javascript

I made an object called Fullscreen, and within the object another object called directions. so my code looks like this:

```
FullScreen = {
  directions: {
    prev: -1,
    next: 1
  }
}
```

but i want to be able to set FullScreen.directions.prev from outside the object, and change FullScreen.directions.next to the negative value of the prev. any ideas how to do this?

Comment: And what is the problem with that?

Comment: Just assign the values to the properties. Have a look at [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to learn the basics about objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it's as simple as this:

```
FullScreen.directions.prev = -42;
FullScreen.directions.next = -FullScreen.directions.prev;
```

It might be better, however, to encapsulate this logic in a function:

```
FullScreen = {
  directions: {
    prev: -1,
    next: 1,
    setPrev: function (value) {
        value = +value; // coerce to number
        this.prev = value;
        this.next = -value;
    }
  }
}

// then
FullScreen.direction.setPrev(-42);
```

You could get even fancier using the [special `get/set` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters):

```
FullScreen = {
  directions: {
    _prev: -1,
    _next: 1,
    get prev() {
        return this._prev;
    },
    set prev(value) {
        value = +value; // coerce to number
        this._prev = value;
        this._next = -value;
    },
    get next() {
        return this._next;
    }
  }
}

// then
FullScreen.direction.prev = -42;
// invokes the setter function behind the scenes, so that _next is also set
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what i meant. first option you mention didn't do anything however. will give it another try!

Comment: What do you mean "didn't do anything?" The code is correct, I assure you.

Comment: nevermind... that also worked. forgot a character somewhere which stopped the script from running
i use this now:
    get next() {return this.prev * -1}
also gives me what i want

Answer (score 0):

To make this happen automagically you'd need to use `get` and `set` functions on the `directions` object.

Ideally you'll have a separate variable which contains the actual value, and each time you `set` one of the properties, you change that variable, but each time you `get` you retrieve the value calculated from that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var directions = {
    current: 0,
    prev: function () {
        return -current;
    },
    next: function () {
        return current;
    }
};
```

And then you can interact with it and modify your `directions.current` instead of either of `next` or `prev` values.