# Setting property value from other property value inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

Is there a way to set the value of a property within an object relative to another property within the same object?

For example:

```
var myObj = {
    prop1 = 10,
    prop2 = prop1 + 5
};

alert(myObj.prop2); //Alerts 15
```

Another example would  be for when I create objects within an object aswell

```
var mainObj = {
    obj1: {x: 100, y:100},
    obj2: {x: obj1+10, y: obj1+10}
};

alert(mainObj.obj2.x); //Alerts 110
```

I want certain properties to stay relative to other properties in the same object, so that when I change one property, it will affect the other property.

Comment: Not really, at least not like that, and why would you need to ?

Comment: I was just wondering because It would make editing properties of some objects easier for my code

Comment: There's functions and object.watch, none of them really do what you're trying to do, but functions, like below, is probably the easiest to add a property and return the result, but it's completely different from what you're doing.

Comment: Well no, that way does work for what I want as it does define a property from another property. It's just not as simple as I'd hoped

Comment: A more complete discussion of [self-referencing properties on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers) – e.g. one option is to use a getter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can declare your properties as functions

```js
var obj = {
  prop1:1,
  prop2:function(){
    return this.prop1 + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: And is this the only way to accomplish this? I feel like using functions will make my code more complicated

Comment: That would be the simplest way to accomplish this. Every time you call obj.prop2() you get a value relative to the current one of obj.prop1

Answer (score 2):

The marked answer is a way around using a function instead of a property. The correct answer to the initial question is using the `get` syntax.

The difference is shown in the following example:

```
var myObj = {
    prop1 = 10,
    get prop2(){this.prop1 + 5}
    prop3 : function(){return this.prop1 + 5}
};

console.log(myObj.prop2); // Prints: 15
console.log(myObj.prop3()); // Prints: 15
```

Similar [post/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10705511/10396046).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about [backwards compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) with browsers that only support ECMAScript 3, you can [use accessors (setters and getters)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) featured in ECMAScript 5:

```c
var myObj = Object.create(null, {
  prop1: {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value: 10
  }, prop2: {
    get: function() {
      return this.prop1 + 5;
    }
  }
});

myObj.prop1       // 10
myObj.prop2       // 15
myObj.prop1 = 20  // 20
myObj.prop2       // 25
myObj.prop2 = 6   // 6
myObj.prop2       // 25
```

See also the [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method, which allows you to add accessors to already existing objects.